# C# convert given format into seconds

Tags: c#

How can we convert given hours and Min format into seconds on C#

Example :Actual string is **"12 hours 14 mins"**
Needs to converted in to = **734**  (Required logic for this)

Because 
734= 12 hours *60 min= 720 min  +14  min
I hope "substring " will help for this or please provide the solution

Comment: split your string by space. index 0 is hour number, index 2 is minutes number.

Comment: So you already know the calculation you need. And you already thought of trying `substring` (which will probably work if you have a reliable input format like that) so... why haven't you tried to do it yet??

Comment: Is line `12 hours 5 secs` possible? `12 mins 15 secs`? `12 hours`? `15 mins`? are `hours`, `mins` are constant? Can we have, say, `12 h 14 m`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: All good questions, and probably enough to justify closing this as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: You could do `TimeSpan.Parse("(google here)").TotalMinutes`

Comment: @Rob... `TotalSeconds`

Comment: @Rob How can you parse this string with `ParseExact` by the way? Is there any chance to parse separated numbers as a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: @musefan Nope, minutes - Though I did realise just now `TimeSpan.Parse()` doesn't allow 'total hours' as an input, so the solution will only work for 0-23 hours.

Comment: @Rob: What do you mean `"Nope"`... OP asked for result in seconds, not minutes

Comment: @musefan Read it again.. plus, there are definitely more than 734 seconds in 12 hours.

Comment: @SonerGönül Something like this: `TimeSpan.ParseExact(str, "hh' hours 'mm' mins'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` - though again, I realized after the comment that it only supports 0-23 for hours and 0-59 as minutes

Comment: If *seconds* are wanted then the answer is `44040 = 12 * 60 * 60 + 14 * 60`

Comment: @Rob lol, I was asking myself why I can't parse this string then I realize I wrote it as `' mins '` instead of `' mins'` :) Thanks by the way.

Comment: @SonerGönül No worries :)

Comment: @Rob: Hmmm... even more reason to close it. Though it clearly says `"into seconds"` twice, and nothing about in to minutes. I'm guessing even the OP doesn't understand what they want, possibly homework assignment with very poor understanding of requirements

Comment: @musefan Sorry you're right, I re-read the question multiple times after seeing your comment and mentally saw it as 'minutes' after seeing the calculation. Sorry for being sharp

Answer (score 2):

An *overshoot* solution for the *unclear* question:

```
String source = "12 hours 14 mins";

String[] chunks = source.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int seconds = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < chunks.Length - 1; ++i) {
  int v;

  if (int.TryParse(chunks[i], out v)) {
    String mark = chunks[i + 1];

    if (mark.StartsWith("h", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      seconds += 3600 * v;
    else if (mark.StartsWith("m", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      seconds += 60 * v;
    else if (mark.StartsWith("s", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      seconds += v;

    i += 1;
  }
}

// Test 44040 = 12 * 60 * 60 + 14 * 60 (you've asked for seconds, right?)
Console.Write(seconds);
```

Supported formats (samples):

```
  12 hours 50 mins 5 secs
  12 hours 5 secs
  12 hours
  15 min
  15 secs
  20 h 30 m 15 s
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you Sir(Dmitry Bychenko)  for Quick response. Got outstanding perfect solution.... Great job .

Comment: Hi @raju if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If the format of input string is always `00 hours 00 mins`, then you can simply use `Split` to extract values:

```
String str = "1234 hours 14 mins";

String split = str.Split(" hours");

int hours = int.Parse(split[0]);
int minutes = int.Parse(split.Split(" mins")[0]);

Console.WriteLine(hours * 60 + minutes);
```

Comment: You are mistaken... there is no question... only "give me the code" instructions.

Comment: ...and I am glad you got rid of that regex suggestion!

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - There isn't at the minute.. (at this second?)

Comment: @musefan Yeah. Using regex was a bad idea. What about code-request-question - I agree. I have downvoted the question, but have provided a short and simple answer, which can help him.

Answer (score 0):

if your string is in constant format:

Regex for hours: `\d+(?=\shour)`

Regex for mins `\d+(?=\smin)`

Why regex and not substring? you play with `1 hour` and `10 hours` so even "s" can change index of substring

to get information how to implement regex look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As suggested by other comments. `string.Split` is probably better